# Return values from a generic Option Array in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-option

I am having some difficulty making my function generic, and need some help. I have an array that takes Option's of T where T is a Fractional. 
In F#, there is a function "choose" which strips None's from a collection of Options. In scala, I am trying to use "flatten", but it does not work with a generic type.

my code is

```
var arr = Array.fill(capacity)(None :Option[T])
```

...
and later I try to get values of the Some's :

```
var flat = arr.flatten
```

error is:

error: could not find implicit value for parameter m: scala.reflect.ClassManifest[U]
val flat = arr.flatten

i am a complete scala noob, and maybe should not play with generics :)
how do i make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Play with generics all you want. Keep arrays away for a bit. They're somewhat hairy on JVM. :-)

Comment: @missingfaktor, lol I need some datastructure that's fast on an instert into a known index, and array is it as far as i can tell right now

Comment: Okay. If you are okay with their performance characteristics, `ArrayBuffer` (mutable) and `Vector` (immutable) are perhaps good alternatives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to create a new generic array, and your method doesn't know how because arrays require type information.  You should then add a `ClassManifest` context bound so that the array knows how to create itself:

```
def flat[T: ClassManifest](bumpy: Array[Option[T]]): Array[T] = bumpy.flatten
val fish = Array(Some("salmon"), None, Some("haddock"))
flat(fish)  // Prints Array(salmon, haddock)
```

Note that if you try to pass the array in directly to the method, it will get confused trying to figure out what type it is; you need the assignment for a val to let it know that the array itself contains all the information about its type, and then `flat` should take its type from the array.

Comment: @oxbow_lakes - Hahaha.  Sorry, I should have picked "flounder" and "halibut".

Comment: @Alex - _Which_ array?  `bumpy` is clearly of type `Array[Option[T]]`.